# Having trouble adding a hyperlink to a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I have a Django app that uses jQuery DataTables for a list view of items. Now I am trying to add a hyperlink to the first element of the table which is the primary key for the model I am displaying. The intent is for the link to take you to a detail view for the model instance. I have what I think should work but it is giving me "undefined" for each item in the datatable and throws an error when you click on it. I think it just isn't picking up the ID of the model instance.

I've tried any variation of the render function that I can think of but I'm new to javascript so I'm a bit lost. I am pretty confident that my app will work once I get this sorted out.

Here is my html:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Part Requests</title>

</head>


<body>

    <h1>Part Orders</h1> 
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="float:right" href="{% url 'New_Order' %}">&nbsp; New Part Order &nbsp;</a>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="PartOrders" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order #</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                    <th>Part Description</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Unit Name</th>
                    <th>UIC</th>
                    <th>End Item</th>
                    <th>Reason For Order</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table> 
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('/api/Order',
            function(data) {
                $('#PartOrders').DataTable( {
                    "data": data,
                    "columns": [
                        { 'data': 'id', 'name': 'id',
                                "render": function(data, type, full) {
                                return '<a href="/order/'+ full.path + '">' + data.id +' </a>';
                            }
                        },
                        { 'data': 'Priority', 'name': 'Priority' },
                        { 'data': 'PartNumber', 'name': 'Part Number' },
                        { 'data': 'PartDescription', 'name': 'Nomenclature' },
                        { 'data': 'Quantity', 'name': 'Quantity' },
                        { 'data': 'OrderDate', 'name': 'Order Date' },
                        { 'data': 'UnitName', 'name': 'Unit Name' },
                        { 'data': 'UIC', 'name': 'UIC' },
                        { 'data': 'EndItem', 'name': 'Aircraft' },
                        { 'data': 'ReasonForOrder', 'name': 'Reason For Order' }

                    ]                    
                });
            });
        });




</script>
</body>
</html>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>



{% endblock js %}
```

and here is my models in case that helps:

```
class PartOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Priority = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('AOG','AOG'),('Rush','Rush'),('Planned','Planned')))
    PartNumber = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    PartDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    SerialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    UnitOfMeasure = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    Quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    OrderDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    UnitName = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    UIC = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    ShippingAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    TimeSinceNew = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    EndItem = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('UH-72A','UH-72A'),('44301-10-7 Hoist','44301-10-7 Hoist')))
    AircraftSN = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    AircrafTime = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Engine1SN = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Engine1_TSN = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Engine2SN = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Engine2_TSN = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    ReasonForOrder = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    RequestedBy = models.CharField(max_length=35)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['Priority']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should refer to the first argument of `render` callback:

```
render: function (data, type, full) => `<a href="/order/${data.path}">${data.id}</a>`
```

- Other than that, I would recommend to use DataTables option [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) rather than wrapping your code with your own `$.get()` success callback - it would give you more flexibility and better integration with DataTables API;
- DataTables/jQuery files are normally included in `<head>` section of the page;
- Plain table header appearing before all the necessary files are loaded may look annoying, so you may set DataTables initialization target node as simple as:

```
<table id="PartOrders" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

DataTables will populate that for you (including header, you simply need to change `columns.name` option for [`columns.title`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title))